# possible to update a property after new model is created in sailsjs?

Tags: database, save, sails.js, insert-update

I am trying to create a new record for a model and there are fields I need to save later after the model is created.

I have the code like this

```
let new_model = await Model.create({ name, type}).fetch();
new_model.content = 'abc';
new_model.save();
TypeError: new_model.save is not a function
```

I googled, it doesn't seem like `sailsjs` can be done this way so I guess I have to use the `update` or `updateOne` by sails.  But the thing is, `name,type` fields are not unique and will not be so using `update` will actually turn into update for ALL records. `updateOne` will give me errors saying there's more than one record though

Does anyone has any suggestions on what can be done here?

Comment: . fetch if your record has a unique identifier. Be weird if it doesn't. But if it doesn't. You could use a combination of field data to make some unique request. As in name, type might not be unique on their own, but unique in combination.

Comment: @Glen new row always has it's own default unique identifier as `id` though and yes somehow weird `.fetch` does not work. I guess your suggestion is pretty much the same as @Dora answer from below?

Comment: So after the create, nothing exists in new_model? I would expect with fetch the created record is what is passed back to new_model.

Comment: @Glen `new_model` does get the records back.  I can `console.log(new_model.content)` or `new_model.name` and I can see the `name` BUT `new_model.save()` gave me an error such as `save` is not a function.  I tried quite a few different ways and none works.  Tried without using `fetch()` too

Comment: But new model is just the record. `.save()` isn't a function of that record. You need to then update the record, you do that by calling Model.update as described by Dora.

Comment: @Glen alright got it thanks, just thought there might be another easier way :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One other option I can think of is doing something like this with `updateOne`

```
let new_model = await Model.create({ name, type}).fetch();
// getting your content here or do something else
const content = 'abc';
new_model = await Model.updateOne({ id:new_model.id}).set({content});
```